# Change/update WMS layer source with new parameters in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, wms

I have a WMS in JavaScript created with GeoServer and OpenLayers. I want to dynamically update the map parameters, for example depending on the chosen year the map should show the data from that specific year.
That is how I show a map:

```
const source = new ol.source.TileWMS({
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/abschluss/wms',
    params: {
      'LAYERS': 'abschluss',
      'TILED': true,
      'CRS':'EPSG:3857',
      'VIEWPARAMS': year
    },
    serverType: 'geoserver'
  });
  
  const layer = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: source
  });
  
  const view = new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([13, 52]),
    zoom: 4
  });
  
  const map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [
      layer
    ],
    view: view
  });
```

Now I want to the user to change the year whenever he wants. So how I can I destroy the previous map or how can I update the map with the new data?

Comment: Use `source.updateParams({'VIEWPARAMS': newYear})` as in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/wms-time.html

Comment: @Mike Thank you. That helped me. I only saw that I have to correct something. It has to be: ```'VIEWPARAMS': 'year:someYear'```

Answer (score 0):

```
source.getSource().updateParams({ 'VIEWPARAMS': 'year:someYear' });
```